# Rails has_many through not returning records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I am trying to setup and use my first has_many through association in Rails 4.2.

I have populated the tables with data and can see associated data across the three tables, but I can't understand if my issue is with model, associations, or table data.

The models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :lists, through: :user_lists

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_lists  
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :users, through: :user_lists
end


class UserList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :list

  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :list
end
```

Sample table data:

```
 users (just showing id and email for particular test user):

 id |       email
----+-------------------
  3 | antman@marvel.com


user_lists:

 id | user_id | list_id 
----+---------+---------
 13 |       1 |       1 
 14 |       2 |       2 
 15 |       2 |       3 
 16 |       3 |       4 
 17 |       3 |       5 
 18 |       3 |       6 


lists:

 id | list_item_id |       list_name        | due_date
----+--------------+------------------------+----------
  7 |              | 1: Coles               |          
  8 |              | 2: Monday way home     |          
  9 |              | 2: Woolworths Sandgate |          
 10 |              | 3: IGA way home        |          
 11 |              | 3: Aldi way home       |          
 12 |              | 3: Pool stuff          |
```

Users Controller:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
end
```

Users View:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>List</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @user.lists.each do |list| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= list.list_name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_list %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_list_path(user_list) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_list, method: :delete, data: { `confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I previously setup a user_lists controller and view and successfully viewed associated user_lists records (the join table) according to currently logged in user.

When trying in the Rails console to test for "any" lists, and similarly for all lists from the associated user (#3 in this case) I get false and nothing:

```
irb(main):001:0> user=User.last
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id"         DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 3, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, username: nil, email:     "antman@marvel.com",...
irb(main):002:0> user.lists.any?
  List Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "lists" INNER JOIN "user_lists" ON "lists"."id" = "user_lists"."list_id" WHERE "user_lists"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 3]]
=> false
irb(main):003:0> user.lists.all
  List Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" INNER JOIN "user_lists" ON "lists"."id" = "user_lists"."list_id" WHERE "user_lists"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
irb(main):004:0>
```

My burning questions in HMT 101 are:

1. I think my issue is in underlying association or data - given rails console fails to return any records, is this the case?
2. I think I should be using Users controller/views to display the data - is this the most appropriate place, or should I use another controller/view?...also taking into consideration I am thinking of implementing an admin interface including master user list maintenance.

Thankyou in advance!
LL

Comment: where are lists with ids 4, 5, 6 referred from join table?

Comment: Thanks Artem - what a silly mistake, and so easily overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample data provided, it seems the IDs for lists 4, 5, and 6 are missing. If this is actually the case, then the join table is referring to records that no longer exist and would not show in the console.

For further help, could you try to create a new list, and give us the output of `user.lists` after saving the record.

For example:

```
user = User.last
list = user.lists.create!({
    list_name: "4: Test List"
})
user.lists
```

This would allow you to see the created list if all the associations are working properly. If not, you would want to review `list` to see what went wrong - whether it's the join table record, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any lists with ids `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6` - the `lists` table only starts with `id` of `7`:

```
 id |
----+
  7 |
  8 |  
  9 |
 10 |       
 11 |
 12 |
```

Your `has_many :through` association looks like it will work perfectly well, it's only that you don't have the matching data for it.

You can use `@codeurge`'s recommendation to create a list if you wanted to test if your relation was working properly.

Comment: Thanks to all - I got stuck and though it was staring me in the face, completely overlooked the missing IDs!  It's working now.